Expose Enum in Swig
I have an existing c++ project with a working swig implementation which is already providing bindings to c#. Several of the methods I want to expose will now require a binding of a c++ enum DependencyType as an argument.
The solution has two projects, a c++ project 'analytics' and the swig cvxproj containing the interface. They are both under the same solution.
The enum is stored in dependency.h, which is located in the same directory as other header files being already referenced by swig already. Nowhere else are there explicit .i file references via the %include directive as used in the example below. The header directory is explicitly added as a path in 'Include Directories' in the properties of the swig project.
How can I expose this enum via swig so that in eg c# I can use DependencyType.Asset directly? I see that with no explicit definition of the enum, swig creates SWIGTYPE_p_DependencyType, but this only provides base swig methods, and the enum members are not present in the c# object.
Should this work out the box? I can bypass this by overloading the methods to accept int, and static_cast this on the c++ side but this somewhat defeats the purpose.
I have created the following:
dependency.i
#ifndef dependency_i
#define dependency_i

%module dependency_type
%{
    #include "dependency.h"
%}
%include "dependency.h"

#endif

dependency.h
#pragma once
namespace dependencies
{
    enum class DependencyType
    {
        None = 0,
        Asset = 1,
        Security = 2,
    };
}

Building with this gives the error Unable to find dependency.h when I try to build.
The current swig command (as detailed in VS Pre-build event
mkdir ..\dotnet\src\ 

swig -c++ -csharp -o "wrap.cpp" -outdir "..\dotnet\src" "..\..\an\src\swig\mxlib.i"

Where mxlib.i contains instructions for building the interface, including a long list of header files and .i files. dependency.h and dependency.i is included here.
%module mxlib
%{
#define _SILENCE_CXX17_OLD_ALLOCATOR_MEMBERS_DEPRECATION_WARNING

#ifdef SWIGPYTHON
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#endif

#ifndef __SSPI_H__
#define __SSPI_H__
#endif

#ifndef __SECEXT_H__
#define __SECEXT_H__
#endif

%{
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include "dependency.h"
[etc]
%}

%include utils.i
%include datakey.i
%include dependency.i
[etc]


%}

I have tried adding the path to dependency.h and the folder containing it via the -I flag when calling swig, however I either get the error:
No module name specified using %module or -module or Must specify an input file.. If I add dependency_i as an additional module name argument, I get this Unable to find file dependency_i

Spelling? depenendency vs. dependency?  Also, are you deleting and re-adding your question it seems like the third time I’ve seen it

Updated now, was typo as I rewrote the Q. And yeah stupidly deleted as I'd made different typos in the previous one when I should have edited.
